# How to convert multi-module maven to gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, multi-module

I would like to **convert a multi-module (java) maven project into Gradle**.

I tried it by running `gradle init` from the folder where parent pom.xml is residing. The process completed with successful status however it did not convert any of the nested maven modules.

Versions I have used:
Maven - 3.3.3
Gradle - 4.3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My experience is, that certain types of multi-module projects do not work. It looks like sub-projects, which use project inheritance from a parent, which is NOT the pom of your root project do NOT work (for example using `spring-boot-starter-parent`).

I checked the integration tests of gradle and the multi-module projects there have sub-projects which DO inherit from the parent pom of their root. These work. See [gradle github](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/build-init/src/integTest/resources/org/gradle/buildinit/plugins/MavenConversionIntegrationTest/multiModule).

Comment: If you share more details about your project poms, maybe we could help better.